# WScript created shortcuts not showing file extensions in filenames

Tags: vbscript

I'm using WScript to generate shortcuts but unlike manually created shortcuts, the filenames don't include the file extensions of the original files. For example, if I create a shortcut in File Explorer with my mouse, let's say "File1.xlsm", the shortcut includes the ".xlsm" part.

Here's an extract of the relevant code.

```
Set objShellWScript = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

If objFolder.Files.Count > 0 Then
    
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        
        With objFile
            
            varFilePath = Replace(.Path, varDestinationFolderPath, varShortcutFolderPath, 1, 1)
            
            Set objShortcut = objShellWScript.CreateShortcut(Replace(varFilePath, "." & objFileSystemObject.GetExtensionName(varFilePath), ".lnk"))
            
            With objShortcut
                
                .Description = objFile.Path
                
                .TargetPath = objFile.Path
                
                .Save
                
            End With
            
            Set objShortcut = Nothing 
           
        End With    
    
    Next objFile  
  
End If

Set objShellWScript = Nothing
```

For what it's worth, I'm using FileSystemObject to loop through the files.

Is there a shortcut property that would help? I've looked around, but the information I've found wasn't particularly helpful. Description shows the file extension to the tootip when you hover over files in File Explorer, close but no cigar.

I've also tried using FileSystemObject MoveFile to see if renaming the files does anything, but no luck.

Comment: It you take an example of the two different types of files, right click and examine the properties, is there any obvious difference?

Comment: The Name property on the Details tab shows the correct file extension for manually created shortcuts, but ".lnk" for code created shortcuts. I'm aware "lnk" is the shortcut file extension, rather than the original file extension, but I don't know to how to make it show the latter.

Comment: Have you tried setting `.Description` to the name you want? I found this reference for the shortcut object https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/all/VBScript/Content/html/5ce04e4b-871a-4378-a192-caa644bd9c55.htm and can't see any special property for name

Comment: No luck. The Description property seems edit the tooltip only. Cold in Brissie?

Comment: For me it's cold. For most other people it's pretty comfortable.

Comment: Don't worry, Summer is on it's way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument you pass to `CreateShortcut` will be used as file name for the shortcut file. The filename, without path and without `.lnk` is shown in the explorer (or on the desktop).

The file name itself doesn't need to match the file name it is pointing to. You can create a shortcut with the name "My Homework" that points to "Book1.xlsx".

If you want to see the file name including extension as shortcut name, you have to pass the filename including extension to `CreateShortcut`. Just add `.lnk` at the end of the file (else `CreateShortcut` will throw a runtime error).

In your code, you are replacing the extension with `.lnk`. Instead, just add `.lnk` at the end of the name (so remove the `rename`) to keep the extension as part of the name:

```
Set objShortcut = objShellWScript.CreateShortcut(varFilePath & ".lnk")
```

Now the full file name of the shortcut is `Book1.xlsx.lnk`. Note that `Book1.xlsx` is the file name (without extension), dots are valid characters in a file name. You even can rename that to `My Homework.docx` - it is still pointing to the Excel file, the file Icon doesn't change and Windows will open Excel, not Word, when clicking on it.

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks! (I wish it was just homework and I was still in my late teens instead of being in my late 50s ;) )